# Add Custom Sql function to hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have created custom sql function in sql server.how to add in hibernate custom dialect

I can able to add predefined sql function.but i could not add created sql function to hibernate.any suggestions?

Comment: are you using nhibernate or hibernate?

Comment: using hibernate @Aniket